# AWS custom label rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rekognition

```
public List<CustomLabel> customLabel(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

//        ByteBuffer imageBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(file.getBytes());
        byte[] imageBytes = file.getBytes();

        DetectCustomLabelsRequest detectCustomLabelsRequest = DetectCustomLabelsRequest.builder()
                .projectVersionArn("project arn")
                .image(Image.builder().bytes(SdkBytes.fromByteArray(imageBytes)).build()).build();

        DetectCustomLabelsResponse response = rekognitionClient.detectCustomLabels(detectCustomLabelsRequest);
//        List<CustomLabel> customLabels = response.customLabels();
        for (CustomLabel customLabel : response.customLabels())
        {
            System.out.println("Custom labels -> "+customLabel.name()+" confident -> "+customLabel.confidence());
        }
        System.out.println(response);
        System.out.println("end"+response.hasCustomLabels());
        return null;
    }
```

when i try to find the custom labels in using my trained model getting the below error

```
2023-12-03T13:42:44.192+05:30 ERROR 20132 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in con
text with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: software.amazon.awssdk.services.rekognition.model.InvalidImageFormatException: Request has invalid im
age format (Service: Rekognition, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 20b5717d-4f26-4a0b-8585-0d56b757b41b, Extended Request ID: null)] with root cause

software.amazon.awssdk.services.rekognition.model.InvalidImageFormatException: Request has invalid image format (Service: Rekognition, Status Code: 400, Request ID
: 20b5717d-4f26-4a0b-8585-0d56b757b41b, Extended Request ID: null)
```

everything seems fine. When i try to upload an image which i took in my cam it throws this error while i check the size, format and properties of it. The issue still persist

Need to detect custom labels